# Matlab 2012a Object Detection and Tracking doesn't work

Tags: matlab, feature-detection, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst

I'm working on my thesis project on indoor localization features but I have no problems with regard to *object detection and tracking* . I am using MATLAB 2012a, but some functions of the code do not work, probably because of the old version of the program. 
Could you give me some advice? 
In particular I have problems with the functions of *showMatchedFeatures* and *estimateGeometricTransform*.
This is the error message:

> Undefined function 'showMatchedFeatures' for input arguments of type 'SURFPoints'.

How can I solve my problem without having to download the new version of Matlab?

This is the code:

`

```
boxImage = imread('img_box.png');
sceneImage = imread('img_desk.png');
I= rgb2gray (boxImage);
K= rgb2gray (sceneImage);

boxPoints = detectSURFFeatures(I)
scenePoints = detectSURFFeatures(K);

figure; imshow(I);
title('100 Strongest Feature Points from Box Image');
hold on;
plot(boxPoints.selectStrongest(100));

figure; imshow(K);
title('300 Strongest Feature Points from Scene Image');
hold on;
plot(scenePoints.selectStrongest(300));


[boxFeatures, boxPoints] = extractFeatures(I, boxPoints);
[sceneFeatures, scenePoints] = extractFeatures(K, scenePoints);

boxPairs = matchFeatures(boxFeatures, sceneFeatures);
matchedBoxPoints = boxPoints(boxPairs(:, 1), :);
matchedScenePoints = scenePoints(boxPairs(:, 2), :);
figure;
showMatchedFeatures(boxImage, sceneImage, matchedBoxPoints,matchedScenePoints, 'montage');
title('Putatively Matched Points (Including Outliers)');



[tform, inlierBoxPoints, inlierScenePoints] = ...
    estimateGeometricTransform(matchedBoxPoints, matchedScenePoints, 'affine');

boxPolygon = [1, 1;...                           % top-left
        size(boxImage, 2), 1;...                 % top-right
        size(boxImage, 2), size(boxImage, 1);... % bottom-right
        1, size(boxImage, 1);...                 % bottom-left
        1, 1];                   % top-left again to close the polygon

newBoxPolygon = transformPointsForward(tform, boxPolygon);

figure; imshow(sceneImage);
hold on;
line(newBoxPolygon(:, 1), newBoxPolygon(:, 2), 'Color', 'y');
title('Detected Box');

end
```

`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Computer Vision Toolbox installed and licensed?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the computer vision toolbox and see whether it is installed or not. Because SURF needs that toolbox. Probably I can suggest u to use SIFT instead of Surf. It is easy to implement. Here is a link that will be useful for you.

[This is a link where you can download the library](http://www.vlfeat.org/)

Here is the tutorial link

[This tutorial will help u more on how SIFT can be used](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html)

Use `ver` command in matlab to check for the installed toolboxes

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox installed you can use the `vision.GeometricTransformEstimator` object instead of the `estimateGeometricTransform` function.

As for `showMatchedFeatures`, it is easy to implement using `imshowpair` and `plot`.

Having said that, lots of cool functions have been added to the toolbox since 2012a, so it may well be worth to upgrade.